# Python: How to call a function repeatedly with a range of arguments?

Tags: python, automation

Let's say I have two functions.

One has two arguments, but one of them is a keyword arg, so it doesn't come up often.

```
def foo(x, _y=1):
  print str(x)
```

The other has one argument.

```
def bar(x)
```

Ideally, It would run `foo` `x` times, each time with `foo`'s `x` argument being one larger (starting at one), until it is ran with `bar`'s `x` argument. Due to the varying number of times it should be run, as well as the fact this number may potentially be in the thousands, it wouldn't be practical to make a slightly-varying line of code for every number between `1` and `x`.

In other words, how would I make a function run multiple times, once for each number in `range(1, x + 1)`?

Comment: Other than with a for loop?

Comment: Use-case here is not very clear about the relationship between the two functions. Seems like a `for` loop would suffice.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ...D'OH!

Yep, I'm an idiot. (HOW COULD I FORGET A FOR LOOP I MEAN WHAT THE HELL)

Comment: Are you saying `bar` should run `foo` `x` times? That's easy: `def bar(x): for val in range(x): foo(val)`

Comment: It would be great if you can explain with a example as what your are tryinng to achieve is unclear

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks! Saves me having to come up with that (though remember, `range`'s upper limit is non-inclusive -- hence, `range(1, x + 1)`

Comment: @tdelaney ...wait. This is affecting the performance of `foo`'s equivalent.

When run on its own, `foo` behaves perfectly normally. But when run with `bar`, things get strange.

For example, if I run `bar(5)`, then the program outputs the equivalent of:

`foo(1)`,
`foo(3)`,
`foo(6)`,
`foo(10)`,
and `foo(15)`

Yet, one of the keyword variables (the equivalent of `_y`) otherwise behaves normally, requiring some arithmetic to even know _in what way_ it's screwing up.

Comment: _[cont'd]_ I'm making a Fibbonachi calculator, which, upon receiving an argument `x`, will check if keyword argument `y = [calls of this function minus 1]` equals it, and if not, will add the two values for keyword list argument `z`, store the sum `temp`orarily, let `z[0] = z[1]`, and let `z[1] = temp`, make `y` increase by one to reflect a running of the operation, then attempt the sequence again with the same `x` and the augmented `y` and `z` args.

Comment: From your description, `bar(5)` should call `foo(1)`, `foo(2)`, `foo(3)`, `foo(4)` and `foo(5)` .... not 6, 10 and etc. I think you need to post code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @tdelaney Right. As I was editing my question to look for different solutions, I remembered one thing:

I will ALWAYS forget to clear keyword arguments when the function succeeds.

This is a direct result of my poor coding practice. Argh! Sorry, I am very inexperienced with python "^^... Thanks for putting up with me...

Comment: ...and then I tried resetting the variables. It didn't work.

...do... do I even know how to clear those properly? God...

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams helpfully points out, this could be done with a simple `for` loop.

After all, with a simple little snippet such as:

```
def bar(x):
  for val in range(1, x + 1):
    foo(val)
```

... we get our goal, for example:

```
bar(5)
```

results in

```
foo(1)
foo(2)
foo(3)
foo(4)
foo(5)
```

(Thanks to tdelany for giving this clumsy novice a tip.)

...I really need to brush up on Python.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri ...yep. Congrats to me, for forgetting one of the most basic parts of Python! (Please forgive me, I'm still getting a hang of it -- I just began learning it about a month ago.)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Fixed it up some. It should be more helpful for clumsy, clumsy novices like myself.

Comment: Much better than before :)